# Select list change event not firing in Firefox or Chrome when using jQuery DataTables / Tablesorter plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

In both plugins the "page size" select list is not functioning properly.  When I change the page size from 10 to say, 20, the table is not updating/refreshing until I click on some random spot on the page.

Why does it take this extra click in order to get the table to update / refresh?  Other select lists on the page that serve as filters for the same table are working fine, it should be noted.

There are no errors, "Break on Next" does nothing, setting breakpoints in Firebug helps me none, and seeing as how it works in IE, I have no idea where to even start.

Comment: If you post the relevant jQuery, or post a demo that reproduces your problem (on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) among others) we might be able to help. Without more detail we could only guess.

Comment: It doesn't work in Firefox or Chrome, but works in IE.

Comment: As far as posting my code, I would not know where to begin, and suspect it would be a boat-load of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I'm cursing up a storm here, but glad I found the problem:

Having tried everything I could think of, I stripped it all down to the minimum, and included only the jQuery and DataTables .js files.  This of course restored the proper functionality.

The next thing I did was add the .js files back in, one at a time, until it broke.  The guilty file, I found, was

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have no idea why, and I'll probably need a drink or two to calm myself down after wasting so much time on this nonsense, and would be very interested in anyone's explanation as to why this file was botching everything up.

Comment: I had a problem with "change" events from `<select>` elements, IE7 and IE8 only, not correctly bubbling to be caught by handlers established with `.delegate()`.  jQuery 1.4.2 exhibits the problem for me, but the new 1.4.3 release does not.